# Is it a must to not use the phrase must to in order to not must to?

Tags: modal-verbs, infinitives

Is it a must to not use the phrase must to in order to not must to?

In my country, Spain similar I think, the most common mistake is saying "I must to do this." Because there's one word for must or have or people don't know the other words.

Comment: I've put the title into the body of the question since the title contains the actual question.   However,  I have difficulty understanding your question.  Can you [edit] your question to make it clearer.  You already know that "must to do this" is a mistake.  So what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, infinitives may be either (1) marked with "to", e.g. "to be", "to have", "to go", or (2) bare, e.g. "be", "have", "go".

"Must" is a modal verb. Modals are followed by bare infinitives: "I must do this", "I must not do this". Likewise "I can do this", "I will do this".

The marked or "full" infinitive is used when you say "I have to do this", "I like to do this", "I want to do this".

Yes, you must avoid saying "must to". "Must to" is ungrammatical.